# jquery initializing cycle plugin dynamically

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-cycle

```
    function ReInitializeCyclePlugin() {
    var el = $("#id");
    var eventobject = EVobject;
    var IdToInitialize = $(eventobject.currentTarget).attr("id");

    /* here first we are detaching the cycle plugin */
    el.find("#" + IdToInitialize).cycle("destroy");

    /* cycle plugin reinitializes here */
    el.find("#" + IdToInitialize).cycle({
        fx: $("#cyclescroll").val(),
        easing: $("#cyclebounce").val(),
        speed: 1000,
        timeout: 2000
    });
}
```

I just want to reinitialize the cycle plugin dynamically as per user given inputs, and I am attempting this through above code.  But there is some problem and it does not work.  It 'destroys' successfully but is not reinitializing.  What's the problems here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried chaining them together?  http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/NTB4s/

```
el.find("#" + IdToInitialize).cycle("destroy").cycle({
    fx: $("#cyclescroll").val(),
    easing: $("#cyclebounce").val(),
    speed: 1000,
    timeout: 2000
});
```